# How to use one Column of Sql query into another sql query inside C# Code

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, ado.net

How to use query1 column `Display Group` into query 2 in the below c# code.

I have denoted the place where i want to put query1 column by `????` symbol.

```
public class PopulateRangeInStore
{

    [Test]
    [Category(TestType.NeedsDeployment)]
    public void PopulateRangeInStores()
    {
        ExecutePopulateRangeInStoreProcedure("csg_sp_populate_RangeInStore");

        using (var connection = IKBDatabaseConnection.GetConnectionForIKBTFS())
        {
            string query1 = "SELECT count (distinct DESC7) FROM ix_spc_planogram (NOLOCK) WHERE dbstatus= 1";
            string query2 = "SELECT count (distinct EquipmentType) FROM Csg_Range_In_Store (NOLOCK) WHERE DisplayGroup = '" + ?????+ "'";
            var command1 = new SqlCommand(query1, connection);
            var command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
            //string output = " ";
            //var  = " ";
            //var actualDG = " ";
            var actualDG = " ";
            var expectedDG = " ";
            var dataReader1 = command1.ExecuteReader();
            var dataReader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
            if (dataReader1.Read())
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dataReader1);
                expectedDG = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
            }

            if (dataReader2.Read())
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dataReader2);
                actualDG = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
            }
            actualDG.Should().Be(expectedDG);



        }

    }


    private void ExecutePopulateRangeInStoreProcedure(string storedProcedure)
    {
        using (var connection = IKBDatabaseConnection.GetConnectionForIKBTFS())
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, connection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ix_sys_error", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;

                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }





}
```

Comment: I can't see the place in your code which you denoted with "????" symbol

Comment: @chameleon86 i have edited just now can.... can u see it now in query 2???

Comment: 1) Attempting to do concatenation like this leaves you open to SQL Injection (potentially, anyways).  2) You're attempting to do a programmatic join, it's almost always going to be faster to do the join on the server and report the result.  3) The only column being output by the first query is a count, which is almost never the correct thing to join on.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by creating a subquery in the place of ???

```
string query2 = "SELECT count (distinct EquipmentType) FROM Csg_Range_In_Store (NOLOCK) WHERE DisplayGroup in (" + query2 +")";
```